# Props alternative to pass the component state to all the components of application in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props

I want to pass the `setState` method of the component (`SnackBar`) to all the child components of the `_app.js`. If I pass the setState method of SnackBar to all the child components of _app.js then it will be a very tedious task. Because, there are approx 4 levels of hierarchy from _app.js to the single component node. It includes,

```
_app.js -> pages -> layouts -> sections -> components
```

The snippet of _app.js is here.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

    const [ toastOpen, setToastOpen ] = React.useState({
        msg: '',
        open: false
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
        pageProps = { ...pageProps, setToastOpen };
    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ToastMessage
                message={ toastOpen.msg }
                setOpenState={ setToastOpen }
                openState={ toastOpen.open }
            />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Is there any way that I can directly import the `setToastOpen` method in the child component and use it whenever I need it?

Comment: you can use react context

Comment: using redux can be an option

Comment: Yes. thank you. I think Context API will be good for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**React have a special Feature called Context Api , using that you can skip the props chain passed into your components..**

I recomend you to checkout below resources to learn about context Api -

- https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-in-5-minutes

---

### Example of ContextAPI

Create a seperate file for Context `Toast-context.js` , You can use any name you want.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
    const ToastContext = React.createContext({
    message: "",
    toastOpen: false,
    toggleToast: () => { },
    changeMessage: () => { }
})

export const ToastContextProvider = ({children}) => { 
/*you need to use 
this component to wrap App.js so that the App.js and all of its children 
and their children components and so on will get the access to the 
context*/

    const [toastOpen, setToastOpen] = useState(false);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

    const toggleToast = () => {
    setToastOpen(true)
    }

    const changeMessage = (message) => {
    setMessage(message);
    }

    return (
        <ToastContext.Provider value={
            toastOpen,
            message,
            toggleToast,
            changeMessage
        }>
            {children}
        </ToastContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

> now in the `App.js` file you need to wrap your components with ToastContextProvider component

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { ToastContextProvider } from "./Toast-context";
import { ToastContext } from "./Toast-context";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const { message, toastOpen, toggleToast, changeMessage } =
        useContext(ToastContext);

    return (
        <ToastContextProvider>
            {toastOpen && <div className="toast">{message}</div>}
        </ToastContextProvider>
    );
}
```

just import the context using useContext Hook in any component you want. you don't need to wrap with `<ToastContextProvider>` in every component.
just use  useContext hook and then you can see the state and as well as call the functions methods to change the state.

Also make sure to refer the above links to learn more about Context Api. Thank You

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It is the exact same thing which I am looking for.

Comment: ```most welcome``` You can also check for Redux and Redux-toolkit.